# javascript find and replace over whole document

Tags: javascript, replace

What is the easiest way to make string replacement in whole document using a table of replacement? I mean having a list of pairs of old and new values to make replacement of all strings in the document (but not the values of input or select elements).

Comment: If you want a better way to do things, you should show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: And also what frameworks/libraries you use.

Comment: I am using wordpress and want to add some js (jQuery may also be used). And what I have? I can use for statement and call something like that  $("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(old,new) );   
});   But there is maybe more sophisticated way and omitting input elements?

Comment: All the methods does not look inside divs, so replacement does not work. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Remember to add jQuery first):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "input" || $this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "select"){
            continue;
        }
        else if($this.text() == "hello"){
            $this.text("Bye");
        }
    });
});
```

If you also want to store a record for older values you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var older_values = [];
    $("body").children().each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "input" || $this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "select"){
            continue;
        }
        else if($this.text() == "hello"){
            older_values.push($this.text());
            $this.text("Bye");
        }
    });
});
```

*** Edit ***
To grab all the elements inside the body tag, just replace the:

```
$("body").children()
```

with

```
$("body").find("*")
```

Hope that works for you

Comment: Thank you for your code. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my case. First if clause causes the problem, but after removing that (and word else of course) code works, but doesn't replace the text (jQuery is added - other functions using jQuery work well). I put alert(this.text()) and it seems, that only highets elements are checked, without digging into divs interiors. And the text I can add in wp is inside few divs.